# File path for AJAX script (in Wordpress)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, variables, filepath

I use this jquery-ajax script to send email:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: process.php,    
        type: "POST",
        data: data,        
        cache: false,
    ...
```

in `url` I call the php file that sends email, but ajax get it only if I specify the full path:

```
url: "http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/site_theme/templates/process.php",
```

but I have to use a syntax like this:

```
url: "../../templates/process.php",
```

or using a variable to declare in the html header/footer

**Html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var urlMail = '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/templates/process.php';
</script>
```

**Script**

```
url: "../../templates/process.php",
```

but with both the above cases the browser console retrieves this error:

```
POST http://www.domain.com/templates/process.php 404 Not Found 1.56s
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried: `url: "templates/process.php",` ?

Comment: What's wrong with specifying the full path?

Comment: @jtheman: with your solution it retrieves this error `POST http://www.domain.com/contact-page/templates/form-contatti-mail.php 404 Not Found 1.34s`

Comment: @Musa: because I will use this script in other projects and I don't want to update the path every time.

Comment: What is actually echoed out from `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` ??? Looks empty if that's your error: `POST http://www.domain.com/templates/process.php 404 Not Found 1.56s`

Comment: it echoes `/site_theme`

Comment: Can't you use `url = '/wp-content/themes/site_theme/templates/process.php';` ?

Comment: @Shikiryu As I said before I will use this script in other projects and I don't want to update the path everytime

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's not the way to implement ajax in wordpress. All ajax request should be made to `admin-ajax.php`.

In your template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
```

In your js:

```
$.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,    
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: data + '&action=sendmail' //action defines which function to use in add_action
});
```

in your functions.php:

```
function send_my_mail(){
#do your stuff
}

add_action('wp_ajax_sendmail', 'send_my_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendmail', 'send_my_mail');
```

Read about [`Ajax in Plugins`](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: I didn't know that. I will read, but i'm not developing a plugin! it's a simple contact form. or i have to use that way everytime I use ajax?

Comment: Tried your code and I get error: `ReferenceError: sendmail is not defined - action:sendmail,` and it reloads the page

Comment: I forgot to put quotes around it. Updating my answer!

Comment: Ok, now no errors, but it doesn't send any email! the firebug console says Response=0 and HTML=0

Comment: You now to write relevant codes in the `send_my_mail` function.

Comment: yes, I copied the code from the old `process.php` to the `send_my_mail` function! Notice: the code worked with the method that I used before (with process.php)

Comment: write something like `die( print_r( $_POST, true ) );` at the beginning of your function to see if it is running. You will see the output in your Console's network tab. I recommend you using `FirePHP` when debugging Ajax.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29112/discussion-between-fred-k-and-rrikesh)

Comment: **Solution**: replace `data: data` with `data: data + '&action=sendmail'`

Comment: I just realised that the action should be **in** the `data` part, not separated.

Comment: instead of writing the js in template file e.g;
`<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>` we can use `wp_localize_script()`

Answer (score 0):

I would be recommended to you use system like Registry for save all "global" values in a one place.

[Registry design pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html)

There is my small jQuery plugin if this is may be interesting to you. [GitHub rep](https://github.com/khaletskiy/jquery-registry)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.Registry.set('urlMail', '<?php get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/templates/process.php';
</script>
```

And to get value from the Registry you must use $.Registry.get('urlMail');

Comment: thanks but I'd prefer to not use a plugin only for that. besides i'm already using that "variable method" with another script and it works. I don't get why it doesn't work for this!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using the code provided by [RRikesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16275126/1252920) but replacing

```
data: data
```

with

```
data: data + '&action=sendmail'
```

Comment: You should really have made @RRikesh's answer the correct answer, since this answer relates to an additional correction to your ajax call and not the original question which relates to to the file path, and which he answered above. I know it sounds fussy, but the green tick is where people go to look for the answer to the question asked.

Comment: I edited RRikesh's answer to make it correct, since it is highest rated. I think this should have been the course in the first place since it is the correct answer and only needed one small edit.