# No email sent with Ajax contact form (in Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to build a simple Ajax contact form in Wordpress, with validation (jQuery Validate plugin) with this code:

**Html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'; 
</script>
```

**Js**

```
$("#form").validate({  //jquery validate plugin

    ... // rules

    submitHandler: function(form) {

    var data = $('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,        
            cache: false,
            action: 'sendmail',

            success: function (html) {           
                ... // succesful message         
            }
        }); 

        return false;

    } // end submitHandler

}); // end Validate
```

**function.php**

```
function send_my_mail(){
    ... //sends email
}
add_action('wp_ajax_sendmail', 'send_my_mail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendmail', 'send_my_mail');
```

When I submit the form the browser console retrieves this ok message:

```
POST http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 200 OK 3.45s
```

but no email was sent. I don't get what's wrong in the code!

Comment: You aren't going cross domains are you? Maybe you should post the actual send_my_mail code.

Comment: "action" is not a jquery ajax option so remove  action: 'sendmail' and add it to your data : data.action = 'sendmail' (or add an hidden field named action with the value "sendmail" to your form)

Comment: @RafH: no, tried with `data: data.action = 'sendmail',` in place of `data: data,` but it's the same

Comment: @FredK Just try and send the mail without the if statement. See if that works for now.

Comment: @user1048676: no, it doesn't send! :\

Comment: Just add an hidden field named 'action' with value 'sendmail' in your form OR modify `data: data` to `data: data + '&action=sendmail'`

Comment: I dont get how wp_ajax_sendmail action can be performed without the action=sendmail in the post vars but if you say so :)

Comment: @RafH: oh hey wait! with `data: data + '&action=sendmail'` it works perfectly! write the answer so I can vote up. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use an "action" option that doesnt exists in jQuery.ajax. You just need to pass the action to WP in the data option like this :

```
$("#form").validate({  //jquery validate plugin

    ... // rules

    submitHandler: function(form) {

    var data = $('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: data + '&action=sendmail',        
            cache: false,

            success: function (html) {           
                ... // succesful message         
            }
        }); 

        return false;

    } // end submitHandler

}); // end Validate
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function?

Also use a different SMTP connection if it doesn't work. You can test with gmail SMTP to see if that is the problem with SMTP you are using.

Comment: Before I used the code that you can see in this question I used the one posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274093/file-path-for-ajax-script-in-wordpress and it sends email perfectly. Then I think the issue is not about Smtp

Comment: when you use simple mail() function it doesn't use WP SMTP provided in wp-config.php