# Fresh wordpress install call to undefined function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, themes

**Hello everyone!**

**It seems that I cannot use any wordpress functions inside functions.php**. I’m creating a theme for wordpress in which I use thumbnails and since in using wordpress version 3.7 I have to state in the functions.php file to add theme support for this. I do this by using . This works for me and I can add images to my post.

But the problems began when I added a script for sending email using ajax to functions.php.([I use the method described in this article](https://spruce.it/noise/simple-ajax-contact-form/)).
The problem here is that I do not get the success message I should and the email won’t send. And when I with ajax return the data from functions.php (I get the same message if I look at it live) I get the message:

```
    <b>Fatal error</b>: Call to undefined function add_theme_support() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\max\wp-content\themes\PortfolioTheme\functions.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
```

So I tried shuffling the functions and add the mailing script above but then I get the same message only for the wp_mail function:

```
    <b>Fatal error</b>: Call to undefined function wp_mail() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\max\wp-content\themes\PortfolioTheme\functions.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

So I tried with some other wordpress functions and the same thing happened and I have no idea why!

I have tried reinstalling wordpress and changing files and so on. The problem could have to do with the theme itself but I don’t know what may cause it. Grateful for any help!

Php version:5.4.19

Wordpress version: 3.7

**functions.php:**

```
    <?php 
    // Email Submit
    // Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
    if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text']) &&       filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

    // detect & prevent header injections
    $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
         if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {

              exit;
         }
    }

     //send email
          wp_mail( "MYEMAIL@something.se", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['text'], "From:" .        $_POST['email'] );

     }
     add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
     ?>
```

javascript(jquery):

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      // Contact Form
    $("#contact").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var name = $("#name").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var text = $("#text").val();
      var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + text;
      function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
      };

      if (isValidEmail(email) && (text.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/max/wp-content/themes/PortfolioTheme/functions.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){

          console.log(data);
          //this wont run b/c of the php error
          funcs.success();
        }
        });
      } else{
        funcs.fault();
      }

      return false;
    });

    var funcs={
        success:function(){
            $("#name").val("");
            $("#email").val("");
            $("#text").val("");
            $('.success').addClass('MsgShow');
            $('.error').removeClass('MsgShow');
        },
        fault:function(){
            $('.error').addClass('MsgShow');
            $('.success').removeClass('MsgShow');
        }
    }
});   
</script>
```

**Theme structure:**

```
    ###################
    #css              #
    #fonts            #
    #images           #
    #js               #
    #                 #
    #404.php          #
    #footer.php       #
    #functions.php    #
    #header.php       #
    #index.php        #
    #page.php         #
    #single.php       #
    #style.css        #
    ###################
```

**EDIT**
[Heres a github link to the theme for easier viewing.](https://github.com/MaxHill/PortfolioTheme)

Comment: As a side note: you should not end your php files with `?>`. Keep the last PHP tag open.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing AJAX wrong!

You are calling `url: "/max/wp-content/themes/PortfolioTheme/functions.php",` as ajax url. This will technically invoke `functions.php` without loading WordPress, hence no WordPress function will be available.

In WordPress, all Ajax calls should be made to `admin-ajax.php` and you must pass a variable called `action` to differentiate between different Ajax calls.

Have a look at the [Codex for examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16275126/1370034).

Answer (score 0):

for emailing filled out forms I just linked the submit to formmail. It has everything already set up and you don't have to add a bunch of code to your functions.php file. I didn't need an ajax style form, so it worked for me.

Comment: Yeah I’ve used “Contact Form 7” before. But I want to use ajax this time. Plus I’m quite puzzled bye the error I get. But if I can’t find a solution something like that will have to do.

Comment: oh I'm not talking about contact form 7, I mean this http://www.scriptarchive.com/formmail.html you should be able to have an ajax based form submit to formmail.php