# Wordpress ajax request call PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

i need to make ajax dependent drop down in Wordpress. i have create a form and function as i mentioned below. but i can't get the ajax requested php page , which is in same function folder.

form input :

```
<input type="text" id="dir-searchinput-category" placeholder="Select Speciality" onblur='changehospital(this.value)'>
```

Ajax Function :

```
function changehospital(choice)
{

    var url="depent-hospital.php";
    var speciality=choice;
    url=url+"?speciality="+speciality;


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        alert("ent");
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            document.getElementById("hospitalDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("get","url",true);
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

How i call ajax request in wordpress...?

Comment: You have an error in xmlhttp.open, it should be url without quotes: xmlhttp.open("get", url, true), also data is undefined.

Comment: Since wordpress usually don't allow you to serve any php-file from anywhere you need to make sure that you have http-access to the depent-hospital.php in the first place.

Comment: Read the codex, wordpress handles ajax in a specific way. http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress have his own method to work with Ajax:
See this post: [File path for AJAX script (in Wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274093/file-path-for-ajax-script-in-wordpress)

**First:** I'd try to separate html from javascript, and I'd use a js framework like jQuery to manage Ajax requests (this is only an advice).
**Second**: Wordpress have his own file to manage Ajax requests: admin-ajax.php (see the link above)
**Third:**  Use the wordpress actions in order to access the functions which resolve the requests (see the link above).